# Sql to LINQ 'where in' query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm trying to convert this SQL query to LINQ

```
select * from fichepfe where valid = 1 and id_fiche in ( select fiche_id from enseignant_fiche where id_ens = '*variable*');
```

This query can return multiple rows.

This is what I tried but I keep getting this error

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'IQueryable'

What I tried:

```
var fiches = (from fiche in _context.Fichepfes where fiche.Valid == true && fiche.IdFiche ==
              (from fens in _context.enseignant_fiche where IdEns == *variable*
              select fens.ficheId )
                  select fiche ).ToList();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var fiches = 
    (from fiche in _context.Fichepfes where 
        fiche.Valid == true && 
        _context.enseignant_fiche.Any(fens => fens.IdEns == *variable* && fens.ficheId == fiche.IdFiche)
    ).ToList();
```

However this may cause part of the query to be executed by the client, since LINQ-to-SQL may be unable to convert the `.Any()` call to a raw query.

A better way would be to use a join:

```
var fiches =
    (from fens in _context.enseignant_fiche where fens.IdEns == ens
     join fiche in _context.Fichepfes on fens.ficheId equals fiche.IdFiche
     where fiche.Valid
     select fiche.IdFiche).ToList();
```

The join can be done the other way around, too, but it's around 5 to 6 times slower on my computer.

```
var fiches =
    (from fiche in _context.Fichepfes where fiche.Valid
     join fens in _context.enseignant_fiche on fiche.IdFiche equals fens.ficheId
     where fens.IdEns == ens
     select fiche.IdFiche).ToList();
```

Comment: @HussamMejry if this answer solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the green tick on the left

Answer (score 0):

So you have a table of `Fiches` (FichePfes), and a table of `EnseignantFiches` (enseignant_fiche).

There seems to be a relation between `Fiches` and `EnseignantFiches`: every `Fiche` has (owns?) exactly one `EnseignantFiche, namely the` EnseignantFiche`that the foreign key`IdFiche` refers to.

Furthermore, every `Fiche` has a Boolean property `Valid`; every `EnseignantFiche` has a (string?) property `IdEns`.

**Requirement**: Give me all `Valid` Fiches, that owns an EnseignantFiche with a value of `IdEns` that equals "*variable*"

```
var validFiches = dbContext.Fiches.Where(fiche => fiche.Valid);
var variableEnseignantFiches = dbContext.EnseignantFiches
    .Where(enseignantFiche => enseignantFiche.IdEns == "*variable*";

var requestedFiches = validFiches.Join(
variableEnseignantFiches,

fiche => validFiche.IdFiche,                 // from every Fiche take the foreign key
enseignantFiche => enseignantFiche.IdFiche,  // from every EnseignatFiche take primary key

(fiche, enseignantFiche) => new              // when they match, make one new object
{
    // Select the fiche properties that yo plan to use
    FicheId = fiche.Id,
    FicheName = fiche.Name,
    ...

    // Select the EnseignantFiche properties that you plan to use:
    EnseignantName = enseignantFiche.Name,
    ...
});
```

In words:

From the table of Fiches, keep only the Valid ones.
From the table of EnseignantFiches, keep only those with an IdEns equal to "*Variable*"
Join these two tables on Primary key equals Foreign key, and Select the properties that you plan to use.

Of course you can do this in one big LINQ statement. Because the query is not executed yet, this won't enhance process speed. It will surely deteriorate readability, testability and reusability.